# NonUniqueResultException Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA in my project. When I request a list of movies made by a particular director, I get:

```
javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 11
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1672) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:198) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.findDirectorsByDirectorId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at net.yukitteru.what_to_watch.controller.MovieController.showMovies(MovieController.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

MovieRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movies, Integer> {
    List<Movies> findAllByDirectorsById(Directors director);
}
```

DirectorRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface DirectorRepository extends JpaRepository<Directors, Integer> {
    Directors findDirectorsByDirectorId(Persons directorId);
}
```

PersonRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Persons, Integer> {
    Persons findPersonsByName(String name);
}
```

MovieController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class MovieController {
    private final DirectorRepository directorRepository;
    private final MovieRepository movieRepository;
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MovieController(DirectorRepository directorRepository, MovieRepository movieRepository, PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.directorRepository = directorRepository;
        this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }


    @GetMapping("")
    public List<Movies> showMovies() {
        List<Movies> m = movieRepository.findAllByDirectorsById(
                directorRepository.findDirectorsByDirectorId(
                        personRepository.findPersonsByName("Mel Brooks")));
        return m;
    }

}
```

I can't understand why when sql querying everything works as it should, but when using expressions to search the repository, it doesn't work properly. After reading similar questions, I didn't find anything that solved my problem.

Directors Entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Directors {
    private Integer id;
    private Movies movieId;
    private Persons directorId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Movies getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "director_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Persons getDirectorId() {
        return directorId;
    }

}
```

Persons Entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Persons {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Directors> directorsById;
    private Set<Actors> actorsById;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void Name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "directorId")
    public Set<Directors> getDirectorsById() {
        return directorsById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personId")
    public Set<Actors> getActorsById() {
        return actorsById;
    }

}
```

Movies Entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Movies {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String releaseDate;
    private Long budget;
    private Long revenue;
    private Double popularity;
    private Integer runtime;
    private Double rating;
    private String overview;
    private Languages originalLanguage;
    private Collections belongsToCollection;
    private Set<MoviesGenres> moviesGenresById;
    private Set<Directors> directorsById;
    private Set<Actors> actorsById;
    private Set<MoviesKeywords> moviesKeywordsById;
    private Set<SpokenLanguages> spokenLanguagesById;
    private Set<ProductionCountries> productionCountriesById;
    private Set<MoviesProductionCompanies> moviesProductionCompaniesById;

    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "release_date", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "budget", nullable = true)
    public Long getBudget() {
        return budget;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "revenue", nullable = true)
    public Long getRevenue() {
        return revenue;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "popularity", nullable = true, precision = 0)
    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "runtime", nullable = true)
    public Integer getRuntime() {
        return runtime;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "rating", nullable = true, precision = 0)
    public Double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "overview", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore 
    @JoinColumn(name = "original_language", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Languages getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore 
    @JoinColumn(name = "belongs_to_collection", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Collections getBelongsToCollection() {
        return belongsToCollection;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieId")
    public Set<MoviesGenres> getMoviesGenresById() {
        return moviesGenresById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieId")
    public Set<Directors> getDirectorsById() {
        return directorsById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieId")
    public Set<Actors> getActorsById() {
        return actorsById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieId")
    public Set<MoviesKeywords> getMoviesKeywordsById() {
        return moviesKeywordsById;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieId")
    public Set<SpokenLanguages> getSpokenLanguagesById() {
        return spokenLanguagesById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieId")
    public Set<ProductionCountries> getProductionCountriesById() {
        return productionCountriesById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieId")
    public Set<MoviesProductionCompanies> getMoviesProductionCompaniesById() {
        return moviesProductionCompaniesById;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: can you please post the whole stacktrace to see where the exception comes from

Comment: Your class naming seems strange. What is the `Persons` class? From the name of the class it seems to be or contain a collection of persons but from the usage it seems to be a single person. The same irritation occurs for the `Directors` class: is this a collection of directors or should it represent a single director?

Comment: This is the automatic generation of entities in IDEA. I can provide the code for the entity classes if it makes things easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that one `Persons` can be many `Directors` (i.e. have directed many movies).

The `DirectorRepository` is therefore wrong:

```
@Repository
public interface DirectorRepository extends JpaRepository<Directors, Integer> {
    Directors findDirectorsByDirectorId(Persons directorId);
}
```

implies that a `Persons` can only ever be the `Directors` of at most one movie.

What should that method return if the `Persons` is the `Directors` of more than one movie? Should it pick one at random? That wouldn't be very useful! And it would leave you wondering: why does `MovieRepository.findAllByDirectorsById()` only ever return one movie?

That is why it was decided that a query method that finds more results than it can return throws a `NonUniqueResultException`.

How you can fix it? You need to declare the `findDirectorsByDirectorId()` method in such a way that it can return multiple `Directors`:

```
@Repository
public interface DirectorRepository extends JpaRepository<Directors, Integer> {
    List<Directors> findDirectorsByDirectorId(Persons directorId);
}
```

and in turn you need to declare the method `MovieRepository.findAllByDirectorsById()` so that it can accept multiple `Directors`:

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movies, Integer> {
    List<Movies> findAllByDirectorsIn(List<Directors> director);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

personsRespository.findByPersosnName() has more than one result, that is a list, since the method has return type not a list, this is what is causing the issue.

Check your database, there must be more data in the Persons table with the same name.

Try creating a method Persons List findPersonsByNameList(String name). Check if this is actually returning a list with only 1 value with the same parameter.

Comment: can you [edit] your answer to explain how he should do to fix the issue ? I mean, the code that he should use

Comment: select p.name from persons as p
where p.name = 'Mel Brooks'

returns 1 match in the result set

Comment: I think you are onto something. However the stacktrace doesn't point to the `findByPersonsName()` method but to the `findDirectorsByDirectorId()` method.

Comment: `findTopByDirectorId()` throws the same error

Comment: @ThomasKläger is right, the issue is with findDirectorsByDirectorId(), check if only one data exists for that directorId.

Comment: What should I do in this case? findDistinctByDirectorId () also doesn't work as expected